# SLES 10 SP1 domU eth0 not up at boot

Tags: networking, xen

I have a SLES 10 SP1 domU on a SLES 11 SP1 dom0 for the purposes of a build server. After moving around some file systems, when I rebooted the domU, the networking no longer worked. When logging in via `xm console`, the only interface that was up was `lo` and the routing table was completely empty except for the route for `lo`. I have `eth0` set to use dhcp, but when I run `ifup eth0` I get the following error:

```
Nov 10 14:26:40 bitvm01 dhcpcd[6385]: timed out waiting for a valid DHCP server response
```

When trying `rcnetwork restart`, I get:

```
Warning: Could not set up default route via interface 
 Command ip route replace to default via 172.30.79.1 returned:
 . RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
 Configuration line: default 172.30.79.1 - - 
 This needs NOT to be AN ERROR if you set up multiple interfaces.
 See man 5 routes how to avoid this warning.
```

If manually set the IP address:

```
ifconfig eth0 172.30.79.250 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 172.30.79.1
```

Then I can ping other hosts. I talked to the person* that originally set up the VM and he couldn't remember if he fixed it in a similar way before or not.

What am I missing? We have other SLES 10 SP1 (non-VM) servers that I used as a crib and that hasn't helped. I'm using a bridge for networking and it looks to be setup correctly on the dom0 with the correct `vif` in it.

---

Note: Said person is setting up another VM, same versions for the dom0 and domU, from scratch  and is having the same problem. He has no issues with setting up a SLES 11 VM however.

Comment: You know that SLES10 is currently at SP4 - don`t you?
As far as I remember SLES10 was usable from SP2 on - and had some severe bugs before that. (just like SLES11 is usable from SP1 on)

Comment: I knew it was greater than SP1. Can't change it though, stuck with SP1.

Comment: Support matrix problem? I usually ignore these for SPs. Anyway - have a look at the SP2-patches in the network-script area. I think this is where that specific bug was located.

Comment: We ship(ped) systems based on just SP1. I'll check the network-script patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues:

- Most important was what Nils already mentioned: SLES 10 SP1 was kind of broken. I replaced the sysconfig package with one from SP3 and then networking finally would function properly. I believe  `/etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/ifup-route` was the offending script, but I replaced them all to be safe.
- The DHCP IP pool in the subnet was very small and so quickly exhausted. More IPs were added and everyone was happy.